# How to resume failed Maven release:prepare from a subsequent phase (and not the failing one)?

Tags: maven

I'm running "mvn release:prepare" and have a failure on phase 11, 'scm-commit-release' due to my scm provider (RTC aka jazz) having problems with my loaded workspace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare 
(default-cli) on project driver-component-root-pom: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] Error code for Jazz SCM create changeset command - 9
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Problem running 'create changeset':
[ERROR] Cannot determine which component to create change set in. Specify a component.
```

I manually performed equivalent commit operations, and would like to resume building with "-rf release:prepare".

I notice that when building this way, however, Maven knows to start exactly at phase 11/17, and fails again.

```
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) @ driver-component-root-pom ---^
[INFO] phase verify-release-configuration
[INFO] starting prepare goal, composed of 17 phases: check-poms, scm-check-modifications, 
check-dependency-snapshots, create-backup-poms, map-release-versions, input-variables, 
map-development-versions, rewrite-poms-for-release, generate-release-poms, run-preparation-goals,
scm-commit-release, scm-tag, rewrite-poms-for-development, remove-release-poms, 
run-completion-goals, scm-commit-development, end-release
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'scm-commit-release'
[INFO] [prepare] 11/17 scm-commit-release
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
.
.
.
(fails exactly the same way again)
```

I'd like to use "-rf release:prepare" and have Maven start at either phase 12/17 'scm-tag' or 13/17 'rewrite-poms-for-development' and continue onward. (See [Maven Release manager prepare phases](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-manager/#prepare).)

Two questions: Is this possible to do?  How does Maven know how to resume with the particular 'scm-commit-release' phase and not earlier phases?

(Thinking the latter could be hacked to replace 'scm-commit-release' with the desired subsequent phase.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, duh. Figures after I post the question I find something.

I knew there was a 'release.properties' file, but i didn't read it closely enough.  Found this encouraging line in it after the third time looking at it:

```
completedPhase=run-preparation-goals
```

(I was grepping files for 'phase' and the failed phase name)

I changed that to the phase I wanted to start at, and success! The mvn -rf begins at the phase I wanted it to restart at.